# Mobile Safari shows hidden back face when in tab view

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

I made a simple flippable element using common techniques and found some strange behavior in Mobile Safari on iOS 7 *(<del>older version also may be affected, unfortunately I can't test them  at the moment</del> older versions also seem to be affected)*, please see the images below or [visit a demo directly on your iOS device](http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/45EAz/embedded/result/).

[image: Normal view] [image: Tab view]
[image]

1. [Editable markup and stylesheet](http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/45EAz/)
2. [Full screen view to visit on your iOS device](http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/45EAz/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="flippable">
    <input id="flippable-trigger" type="checkbox">
    <label for="flippable-trigger" class="flippable-faces">
        <div class="flippable-face-front">
            Front
        </div>
        <div class="flippable-face-back">
            Back
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

```
body {
    font: 1em/0 Arial;
    background-color: silver;
}

.flippable {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
}

.flippable input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.flippable-faces,
.flippable-face-front,
.flippable-face-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.flippable-faces {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 600ms;
}

.flippable-face-front,
.flippable-face-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 10rem;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1rem gray;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flippable-face-front {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

.flippable-face-back {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flippable input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .flippable-faces {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: you faced the problem which version of Os

Comment: @iDev See my question, I faced this on iOS 7.0.2 but at least the latest iOS 6 is also affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that repositioning your divs fixes the issue. I don't have an answer as to why that was happening though. Sorry. [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/45EAz/3/) | [Example for iPhone](http://jsfiddle.net/45EAz/3/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="flippable">
    <input id="flippable-trigger" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="flippable-trigger" class="flippable-faces">
        <div class="flippable-face-back">
            Back
        </div>
        <div class="flippable-face-front">
            Front
        </div>
    </label>
    </input>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this fixes the issue and thus deserves the bounty, but I still hope for an explanation.